# ¿Cuando escribo un libro y cambio de idioma, solo lo cambio o lo pongo entre comillas, cursiva, entre paréntesis o como?

Tags: escritura

El libro está en español pero se supone que está en ingles, quiero hacer como que la chica habla en español pero no se cómo poner

Answer (score 1):

No sé si hay reglas por cosa así, mas sugería que use comillas normales.  El cambio de idiomas será obvio sin necesidad de ponerlo en cursiva.  Si le sirve mejor, también es posible usar comillas de tipo diferente.  Es común en España, por ejemplo, usar «comillas así», mientras en inglés, normalmente se usan "estas comillas."  Sin embargo, pienso que tampoco hace falta distinguir de esta manera como la lengua ya es distinta.